# "Assigned To" column should not be clickable

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have a custom list containing "Assigned To" column with "Show Field" option set to "Name"

When I enter the user name in the column and save it, by default the user information is created as hyperlink and when clicked it will navigate to user profile information of that user.

My requirement is it should not go to user profile information. Is it possible using designer? Or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with Designer. You need to convert the view to an XSLT dataview and then you can do xslt substring operations to extract the name from the field.

I've done it several times using a technique similar to this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@MyColumn, '&gt;'), '&lt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

In the case of people columns, you need to fiddle with the before and after so you are isolating the proper part of the string.

http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2012/02/sharepoint-2010-removing-the-hyperlink-in-xsl-for-a-lookup-column/

Comment: Hello Eric, Thanks for the reply. I have already tried that but its not working. When I replace it and save it, the column goes blank. It should reflect in the dispform

Comment: Try it in pieces then, first just do <xsl:value-of select="@MyColumn" disable-output-escaping="yes" /> to make sure it is spitting out the right information, then identify where you need to substring to get the desired information.

Comment: I've used this method several times in many pages and it works, provided you manipulate the substrings properly.

Answer (score 0):

One other way would be to just create an additional text column called "Assigned" as single text and create a simple designer workflow that starts on item created and item updated with the following logic:

```
Update item in Current Item > Set "Assigned" to blank value.

then Update item in Current Item > Set "Assigned" to "Assigned To".
```

What it does is to first blank out the new "Assigned" Text column if there are any old values, and then set it to any name from the "Assigned To" people picker column.

Then in the list view, show only the text column and hide the people picker column, and in the list form, hide the text column.